# iPhone 5c SIM card switch and have data on new one?

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 5C, and my grandpa pays my bill. If I buy at new iPhone 5s and put my SIM card from the 5c in, would I still have data and service? From just switching the SIM?

Comment: what carrier are you on?

Comment: There are 2 conversations happening here, how to transfer the contents of the phone (iCloud or iTunes backup, iTunes being the more reliable) and how to transfer the cell account. The process of transferring the cell account depends on the carrier you have. The easiest way to do it is to walk into a carrier store with both phones and ask them to activate the new phone.

Answer (score 1):

A SIM may be removed from one device and inserted into another and the phone number and attendant account will then be associated with the new device.

Answer (score 0):

I think transfer contacts to Sim card is possible anymore, but you can work on this article :

http://developer.vodafone.com/discuss/question/833/how-do-you-transfer-contacts-from-iphone-to-sim-card/

But for a fully backup, you have to use iCloud :

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12520?locale=en_US